# Selenium - not all the li elements of a page available

Tags: java, html, selenium, html-lists

under the ul element in the HTML page I have 700 li elements.
when I try to get the list of all the li elements, I get back only 107 instead of all the 700.
Apologies for not posting the HTML source - it is a page requiers a Login password.
the code in Java below:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    List<WebElement> childs;

    elements = driver.findElements(ByTagName.tagName("form"));
    element1 = elements.get(0).findElement(ByTagName.tagName("iframe"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(element1);
    //wait for page load
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    childs = (driver.findElement(By.id("Scroller")).findElement(By.tagName("ul"))).findElements(By.tagName("li"));
```

Childs.size will show 107 and not like the real HTML page has.
can someone please try to help?

Comment: can't really tell what is wrong without seeing the html. If the list is populated by ajax, there might only be a few `li` items added to the list. Can you see all 700 when you do view page source?

Comment: thats the thing, if I right click the first item on the page and choose inspect element, i see part of the li in the source (about 100) and not all of it but if i will inspect element of a higher row in the list - like the 100 row, the source will be opened with more li, its hard to explain, I hope its clear. I dont know how to show the HTML since its an inner system in my work..